# Exit value 2 when upgrading to android support library v23.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I get

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

when trying to upgrade android support libraries from `23.0.1` to `23.1.0`

Comment: post `build.gradle` please

Comment: Problem may with unnecessary library Try to remove libraries which is not needed; Have you tried with "multiDexEnabled true" ?

Comment: I have tried adding multidex support and it worked. Then I realized that I have the complete google services which I don't nedd. Removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried adding multidex support and it worked. Then I realized that I have the complete google services which I don't need. Removing it fixed the problem.